# Django test returning _wrapped_view as view name instead of proper view name

Tags: django, view, decorator

In my django project I usually test if the view being called is correct using:

```
viewName = resolve(response.request["PATH_INFO"])[0].func_name
self.assertEqual(viewName,'correct_view_name')
```

I was able to do it successfully until I added a decorator. Since then, my views are working normally, but I'm unable to test (at least like this) the correct view name.

The decorator I added looks like this:

```
def owner_required(view_func, Model):
    '''
    checks if the object is being accessed but its owner
    '''
    def decorator(view_func):
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = Model.objects.get(pk=int(kwargs['pk']))
            if obj.user == request.user:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponse('You don't have access to this page.')
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator(view_func)
```

The result of `resolve(response.request["PATH_INFO"])[0].func_name` when I apply this decorator is always "_wrapped_view"

How can I make the view name go back to normal?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) in your decorator.

```
try:
    from functools import wraps
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.functional import wraps  # Python 2.4 fallback.
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

def owner_required(view_func, Model):
    '''
    checks if the object is being accessed but its owner
    '''
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            obj = Model.objects.get(pk=int(kwargs['pk']))
            if obj.user == request.user:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return HttpResponse('You don't have access to this page.')
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator(view_func)
```